# How to charge AirPods to keep battery healthy?

Tags: battery, airpods

Once on the official Apple website it was written to keep iPhone's charge between 20% and 80% for better battery life.

I've not found exact battery specs for the AirPods (I am about 2nd gen), probably they have the same battery type as latest iPhones (Li-ion).

So, do I have to keep AirPods with at least 20%+ charge while using? I can't keep them 20%-80% because of case will charge them even they are at 99% battery.

Answer (score 11):

> ... do I have to keep AirPods with at least 20%+ charge while using?

No.  Use the AirPods for what you purchased them for - wireless headphone with Siri control.

Lithium ion batteries don't need to be micro-managed like previous generation batteries needed to. They don't develop a memory and will function (generally) for their usable life.

The key to this is to understand that [age and cycle count is, by far, the largest factor in determining battery health](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/194703/119271).  You can *mitigate* factors that will diminish battery life like avoiding extreme temperatures and physical trauma but there's no procedure or practice you can do that will extend the [life of the battery](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/342147/119271).

> I can't keep them 20%-80% because of case will charge them even they are at 99% battery.

This is also not an issue and a misunderstanding of how charging works.   Batteries and chargers are "smart" in that they will [automatically reduce/stop charging when it reaches a full charge](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/287593/119271).  Batteries naturally discharge without use, and the charger will kick back in recharging the battery.

The good news is Apple has official battery service options now and some third party companies are also competing in the battery repair service space.

- https://9to5mac.com/2021/02/09/what-to-do-with-old-dying-airpods/

Comment: Leaving batteries in a heavily charged or discharged state is bad for them, (some batteries are best stored fully charged, like lead acid & LiFePo4's, but not the LiPo's from the airpods) - there is minimal management on them, thus they will die out fast - compare to the battery management system of an electric vehicle that will limit the range from around 30% to 80% (it will go into a "limp" mode under 30 & be able to regen past 80), but those same chemistry batteries last longer - air pods & similar just aren't managed in a way to extend their life other than the bare minimum

Comment: Li-ion is a sensitive battery chemistry that just *wants* to tear itself apart, and its life is shortened by 1) Leaving it at a high state of charge 2) Leaving it at a low state of charge 3) Lots of charge cycles 4) Leaving it too long without a charge cycle 5) Looking at it funny 6) etc.

Answer (score 1):

What Allan said is pretty spot on. To make things more clear, lithium ion batteries do best when the charge is around 50%. In order of most to least importance:

- Don't let the battery get to 0. Deep discharge cycles are extremely damaging for the battery. If you do let it get to 0, make sure you charge it at the next possible opportunity, because the longer the charge is at 0 the deeper the discharge (due to "phantom drain" and other things).
- Don't charge to 100%. (Side note: 100% is arbitrarily defined, but usually 4.2V). As with empty batteries, try to keep the time it's at 100% to a minimum.
- Keep battery between 10% and 90%, or 20% and 80%, or 25% and 75%. But we're getting into diminishing returns territory. The lifespan of the battery (if you follow all of the above) is going to be hundreds of cycles even with bad batteries, thousands of cycles with good ones.

To summarize: look at how much you're usually using them. If you use about 50% of the battery try to keep them between 25% and 75%, if you use 80% try to stay between 15% and 95%.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. If I understand the problem correctly, we’re looking for a solution to make sure that the AirPods don’t discharge while not in use, as well as the don’t get charged beyond 80% when in the case. Keeping a charge levelled doesn’t work so far because the battery is always drained while not in the case