# Magic Mouse 2 shows up after connecting with cable but still doesn't work

Tags: mouse

My Magic Mouse 2 is not discoverable via Bluetooth. I tried connecting it with lightning cable, it showed up in the settings but still didn't connect to the laptop.
[image: Magic Mouse 2 in System Settings]

Also, when I turn off the mouse while still connected with the cable, I get a notification on my laptop that it has been turned off. But if it is not connected with the cable, I get no notification. **What could be wrong and how to fix it?**
[image: Mouse Off Notification]

Comment: Try clicking on the bluetooth icon in the menu bar (very top of your screen) and clicking on "Reset the Bluetooth module". Then try again.

Comment: Do other Bluetooth devices connect to your Mac?  Can you try the MM2 with a different Mac?

Comment: @Thinkr I tried that. Didn’t work.

Comment: @Allan Yes, other Bluetooth devices are connecting and working. And same thing is happening with the other Mac as well. I get the ‘Mouse Off’ notification when it is connected via cable. Otherwise, no action.

Comment: So it seems to be a problem with the mouse

Comment: @Thinkr The mouse has been used very less. It's few years old though but in a brand new condition. It was working fine few weeks back. All of a sudden it gave up.

Comment: How old is the mouse?

Comment: @Allan Got it around 2018/'19. Don't remember the exact year.

Comment: It sounds like the battery has died. They have an [expected life of 3 to 5 years](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/342147/119271).

Comment: @Allan Okay. I'll take it to Apple then. Let's see how much they charge.