# magic mouse immediately loses charge

Tags: battery, bluetooth, mouse, charging

When I charge my Magic Mouse 2 to full charge, unplug it, and then immediately plug it back in, the battery meter reads 3% and gradually creeps back up to 100%. Does this mean the rechargeable battery is done for? The mouse is only 3, maybe 4, years old.

When not plugged in, the mouse cannot connect over Bluetooth, although Bluetooth is otherwise working on my computer. I'm guessing this is because the mouse in fact has no power when not plugged in, but it could be something else.

Comment: See this potential helpful post:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/342145/119271

Comment: @Allan Maybe so. Those posts describe similar seeming situations in which it is concluded that the battery is dead. However, neither post gives an explanation of how to diagnose the problem. I was hoping there was a test I could do to know for sure what's wrong.

Comment: There really isn’t a diagnostic you can run, rather it’s determined by symptoms.  The age factor is big plus the fact it won’t connect.  You can try pairing it to another computer.  If it fails there too, it’s a failed mouse.  If you have other BT devices working properly, you’ve ruled out your Mac.

Comment: @Allan Okay, thanks, I'll try pairing to another device and if that doesn't work, declare the mouse dead.

Comment: In the linked dupe, the OP says he found a source for the battery and a guide on iFixit to replace it.  Maybe that’s an option